# Can we set page size in Windows OS

Tags: windows, memory, operating-system

Now I  am learning about virtual memory. I checked the size of each page by use SYSTEM_INFO structure in C and I known each page have 4096 byte. Have anyway to set page size to other value?

Comment: NO! ...........................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page size is fixed by the OS and hardware.